# Fetch Url missing OData query

Tags: reactjs, odata, fetch

Here I'm trying to get data from "Projects" table and other related tables "Client" and "ProjectOwner" below is the OData query.

```
http://localhost:52484/Projects?$expand=Client($select=Name),ProjectOwner($select=Name)
```

If we inspect our React code it shows fetch url without OData query.

Below is the Inspect result:
[image: Inspect result]

React code for to get response

```
import buildQuery from "odata-query";
const queryNotRegisted = buildQuery({
  expand,
  count,
  filter: { Registrations: null }
});


 <OData baseUrl={baseUrlSubproject} query={queryNotRegisted}>
                  {({ loading, data, error }) => (
                    <div>
                      {loading && (
                        <span>
                          Loading... (()=>{console.log(loading)}){" "}
                        </span>
                      )}
                      {data && data.value.length}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </OData>
```

Note : Facing this issue when I use buildQuery for query.

Why my query is not appended to the fetch Url when I use buildQuery ? Please let me know if I'm missing out something.

Comment: Seems that you're missing `?` before query parameters

Comment: I have added ? before query but still  query is not appending to fetch Url.